# XAML designer issue in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio

Hello to all sorry for my English I'm Italian, I have a problem for 2 weeks with the Designer of visual studio 2015, I program in Visual Basic for windows phone 8.1 app on windows10 platform and the designer shows me the following error and I can not find a solution, this problem appears when I create a new Windows Phone 8.1 application empty (no silverlight), while for all other applications the designer works.
I noticed that XDesProc.exe for this type of app does not start, while it is present in all other apps
Thanks for your help

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
XAML parsing failed.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsPhoneXamlDesigner.InstanceBuilders.StatusBarStandIn..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsPhoneXamlDesigner.InstanceBuilders.WindowsXamlPhoneOverlayLayer..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsXamlPhoneImageHost.WindowsXamlPhoneSceneWrapper.CreateOverlayLayer()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsUIXamlImageHost.WindowsXamlSceneWrapper..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsXamlPhoneImageHost.CreateSceneWrapper()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsUIXamlImageHost.get_RootInstanceWrapper()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsUIXamlImageHost.get_OverlayLayer()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsXamlSceneView.get_OverlayLayer()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsPhoneXamlDesigner.UI.PlatformPane.WindowsXamlPhonePlatformPaneModel.UpdateStatusBarVisibility()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PlatformPane.PlatformPaneModel.set_SceneViewContract(SceneViewContract value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.UI.PlatformPane.WindowsUIXamlPlatformPaneModel.UpdateContract()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.UI.PlatformPane.WindowsUIXamlPlatformPaneModel.OnSubscriptionBasisNodeInserted(SceneNode newBasisNode, DocumentNode basisContent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PlatformPane.PlatformPaneModel.Subscription_BasisNodeInserted(Object sender, SceneNode newBasisNode, DocumentNode basisContent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.ViewModel.SceneNodeSubscription`2.OnBasisNodeInserted(BasisNodeHolder holder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.ViewModel.SceneNodeSubscription`2.SetBasisNodesWorker(SceneViewModel viewModel, DocumentNodeMarkerSortedListOf`1 newBasisNodeList)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.ViewModel.SceneNodeSubscription`2.SetBasisNodes(SceneViewModel viewModel, IEnumerable`1 basisNodes)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PlatformPane.PlatformPaneModel.set_ActiveView(IDeviceOptionsView value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PlatformPane.PlatformPaneService.GetModel(SceneView sceneView, Boolean setActiveView)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PlatformPane.PlatformPaneService.UpdateActiveModel(SceneView view)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PlatformPane.PlatformPaneService.DocumentViewContext_ActiveViewChanged(Object sender, ViewChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OnActiveViewChanged(ViewChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.SetActiveDocumentAndView(SceneView view, Item item, HostViewEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.SetActiveView(SceneView view, HostViewEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateAndOpenViewInternal(SceneDocument document, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean activate, Boolean ensureOpenInHost)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

>Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
XAML parsing failed.

>Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   in System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   in System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<MarshalOut>b__0()
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
XAML parsing failed.
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

Comment: you should edit this a bit to make it more clear, the error log is quite long

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in designer as well. This is happening with several Windows Phone 8.1 apps I've built. I'm using VS2015 on Windows 10 O/S. The designer was working fine when I first worked on these apps but I think after one of the windows 10 updates this exception started happening. Have you found a solution to this?